# Get rid of second legend in ggplot2

Tags: r

got some problems with ggplot2 again

I want to plot at least two datasets with two different colors and two different shapes.
This works but when i try to put the names for the legend it doubles the legend automatically.
The number of datasets can change and so the legendnames of course. 
I`d need a code that not just works for this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
xdata=1:5
ydata=c(3.45,4.67,7.8,8.98,10)
ydata2=c(12.4,13.5,14.6,15.8,16)

p <-data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=3))

p$X1 <- xdata
p$X2 <- ydata
p$X3 <- ydata2


shps <-c(1,2)
colp <-c("navy","red3")

p <- melt(p,id="X1")

px <-ggplot(p,aes(X1,value))

legendnames <- c("name1","name2")

px <- px +aes(shape = factor(variable))+
geom_point(aes(colour =factor(variable)))+
theme_bw()+
scale_shape_manual(labels=legendnames,values =shps )+
scale_color_manual(values = colp)
px
```

This gives me this:

[image]

But i want that with my legendnames

[image]

I just deleted the `labels=legendnames,` in scale_shape_manual

So whats the issue to solve that problem.
Please help

Comment: you can turn off legend for specific scale by doing scale_zzzzz(guide = 'none'). For example scale_color_manual(guide = 'none', values = colp). For geoms you can do similar geom_zzz(show_guide = FALSE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just a matter of providing the same `labels` parameter to the `scale_color_manual`, otherwise it doesn't know how to consolidate the legends together.

So

```
px <- px + aes(shape = factor(variable)) +
   geom_point(aes(colour = factor(variable))) +
   theme_bw()+
   scale_shape_manual(labels=legendnames, values = shps)+
   scale_color_manual(labels=legendnames, values = colp)
px
```

Comment: Wow, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a problem, you programmed it in yourself by using legendnames (which it then adds, even though those variables are not on your data). If you remove them, the plot behaves as you want:

```
shps <-c(X2=1,X3=2)
colp <-c(X2="navy",X3="red3")
#easy if you want to rerun code, don't overwrite variables
p2 <- melt(p,id="X1")




px <- ggplot(data=p2) + geom_point(aes(x=X1, y=value,shape=variable,colour=variable)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=shps)+
  scale_color_manual(values=colp)
px
```

[image]

Comment: I dont get what you wanted to show me I want exactly this plot with my legendnames,but here it is X2 and X3 again.Thanks anyways